# Changing the recovery rate of SIR model

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, eon

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter

def test_transmission(u, v, p):

    return random.random()<p


def discrete_SIR(G,w,initial_infecteds,beta,Vl,duration):

    if G.has_node(initial_infecteds):
        initial_infecteds=[initial_infecteds]           

    N=G.order()
    #t = [tmin]
    S = [N-len(initial_infecteds)]
    #I = [len(initial_infecteds)]
    R = [0]
    V = [0]

    susceptible = defaultdict(lambda: True)  
    #above line is equivalent to u.susceptible=True for all nodes.

    for u in initial_infecteds:
        susceptible[u] = False

    infecteds = [{}]*duration  #bunch of empty sets  
    infecteds[0] = set(initial_infecteds)

    I = [sum(map(len, infecteds))]  #set I[0] to be the total number of infections

    while I[-1]>0 :
        new_infecteds = set()
        vaccinated= set()

        for u in infecteds:
            for v in G.neighbors(u):
                if len(vaccinated)+V[-1]< (Vl*N)  : #check if vaccination over or not


                    if susceptible[v] and test_transmission(u, v, w): 
                        vaccinated.add(v)
                        susceptible[v] = False
         #               print('transmitting vaccination')

                    elif susceptible[v] and test_transmission(u,v,beta):
                        new_infecteds.add(v)
                        susceptible[v]=False
         #               print('transmitting infection')
                else:

        #            print("BYE")
                    if susceptible[v] and test_transmission(u, v,beta): 
                        new_infecteds.add(v)
                        susceptible[v] = False

               #infector[v] = [u]
        recovering_nodes = infecteds.pop()

        infecteds.insert(0,new_infecteds)      


        infecteds = new_infecteds

        I.append(sum(map(len, infecteds)))

        R.append(R[-1]+I[-1])
        V.append(len(vaccinated)+V[-1])
        S.append(N-V[-1]-I[-1]-R[-1])




    return scipy.array(S),scipy.array(V), scipy.array(I),scipy.array(R)



m=100
w=0.2
#ran=nx.gnp_random_graph(100,0.003)
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(m,m,periodic=True)

initial_infections = [(u,v) for (u,v) in G if u==int(m/2) and v==int(m/2)]



S, V, I, R = discrete_SIR(G,w,initial_infecteds=initial_infections,beta=0.5,Vl=1,duration=8)
```

This is a code of SIR model but this is for recovery rate 1. I want to change this code to include a variable parameter recovery rate and not the default which is 1 in this case. I have tried to change the code to include that. The basic code is of a SIR model.

I added the changes as made from Joels post in my modified SIR model.

For book keeping-

```
    next_time = t[-1]+1
    if next_time <= tmax:
        for i in infecteds:
            for u in i:
                node_history[u][0].append(next_time+duration)
                node_history[u][1].append('R')
        for j in new_infecteds:
            for v in j:
                node_history[v][0].append(next_time)
                node_history[v][1].append('I')
```

Comment: Do you want them to recover with probability q in each time step and transmit with probability p?  Or are you thinking about something different?  In the first case, some small modifications of this code will work.  In the second case, you may end up needing to look at `EoN.fast_nonMarkov_SIR`.

Comment: @Joel for the first timestep the initial infected nodes will infect with prob p. Lets say 5 of them got infected. Those five nodes will keep on infecting with prob p at each timestep till they are not recovered after Tr timesteps.

Comment: I need to clarify a bit more.  If 5 of them get infected, how do we decide when those five recover (do all nodes have the same duration?  Some more complicated distribution?).  And during their infection, do they all transmit with probability `p` in each time step or does it vary during their infectious period?

Comment: @Joel if the recovery rate is 10 then the infected nodes get recovered after 10 timesteps from the time they were infected. During there infection they will infect will the same probability p at each time step till they recover

Answer (score 0):

Let `infecteds` be a list of sets, such that `infecteds[T]` are those just infected, `infecteds[T-1]` are those that have been infected for 1 time step, etc.  Then pop off `infecteds[0]`  [e.g., `recovering_nodes = infecteds.pop(0)`] and append the newly infected nodes to the list.

Then for each time step, just iterate through all the sets in infecteds.

Here's some relevant pseudocode:

```
duration = 8
infecteds = [{}]*duration  #bunch of empty sets  
infecteds[0] = {1,2,3}
I = [sum(map(len, infecteds))]  #set I[0] to be the total number of infections

while I[-1] >0:
    new_infecteds = {}
    for infected_set in infecteds:
        for infected_node in infected_set:
            Do some stuff with the node and its neighbors.
            new_infecteds gets some things added to it.
    recovering_nodes = infecteds.pop()

    infecteds.insert(0,new_infecteds)

    for node in recovering_nodes:
        update status and do any bookkeeping.

    I.append(sum(map(len, infecteds)))
```

---

Be careful about your use of the word "rate".  A higher rate should mean faster recovery, and thus shorter duration (duration is like 1/rate).  Your comment seems to use the word "rate" to mean "duration", so that for you a higher "rate" is actually a longer "duration".  This is the inverse of what most people would understand you to mean.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer with some examples?..I couldnt understand

Comment: I couldnt understand why are you popping off the infecteds after they infect for one timestep?..shouldnt they be infectiing for the entire duration of 8?

Comment: `infecteds` consists of a bunch of different sets.  I'm only popping off the ones that have been infected for `duration` units of time.  The other lists remain in the collection.

Comment: and what is the use of recovering_nodes? Is it for only bookkepping?

Comment: I also made the changes in my SIRV model but it doesnt work. I have added the modified code in the question.

Comment: Is the pseudocode correct?..Initially we have infecteds[0]={1,2,3}. After iterating through all the neighbors of 1,2 and 3 you pop it off...they should keep on infecting for 8 timesteps

Comment: Yes - it is correct.  I pop off an empty list the first iteration.  Initially `infecteds = [{1,2,3}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]`.  After the first loop, I do `infecteds.pop()` which removes the final entry, not the first.  I insert the new infecteds at the beginning, so now we have `infecteds = [new_infecteds, {1,2,3}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]`

Comment: shouldnt the infecteds.pop() be inside the for infected_set in infecteds loop then?

Comment: What the code does right now is that it keeps 8 sets of infecteds.  The sets are in order by how long they have been infected.  At each time step, individuals in all 8 sets get a chance to transmit.  Then, after all of the transmissions are done, the oldest set recovers (they are removed from `infected_sets`) and the newly infected individuals become infectious (they are put at the beginning of `infected_sets`).

Comment: initially the loop will run 8 times with the nodes {1,2,3} infecting once...but i dont see the part where the nodes {1,2,3} are infecting the graph for 8 times and the nodes which get infected start infecting for 7 timestep,6 timestep etc till the loop finishes for 1 duration and we pop off {1,2,3}

Comment: Basically I am confused where this step is happening "At each time step, individuals in all 8 sets get a chance to transmit"

Comment: Each pass through the loop `while I[-1]>0` is a new time step.  I recommend going through the steps by hand, tracking what all the variables are.

Comment: How do I update the node_history of nodes with time for this?

Comment: I have added the code for updating the node_history

Comment: There are a couple problems.  I don't want to debug it directly since it's better that you learn some steps to debug it.  To do that, put in `print('i', i)` at the start of the loop over `i` and `print('j', j)` at the start of the loop over `j`.  Before it runs, think about what you want it to be.  Then check what it actually is.  I think you'll have some surprise.